# Stripe execution order js onComplete and webhook

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, webhooks, checkout

I use Stripe checkout with a webhook call on checkout.session.completed which activates a PHP script and a javascript call when the payment is completed:

```
const handleComplete = async function() {
            _paiement.verif(checkout);
        }
        const checkout = await stripe.initEmbeddedCheckout({
            clientSecret,
            onComplete: handleComplete
        });
```

I didn't have a problem with test cards or normal bank cards but when doing a test with a virtual card (Pennylane) the javascript call is made before the webhook call which poses a problem for me because the javascript call I use to check that the webhook call went well.

Did I miss a setting, misuse these functions...?

Comment: The code you've shared is fine. If this only happens with one card, it is possible that you're hitting some sort of an edge case. I'd recommend creating a support ticket with Stripe along with all the info you have (I'd also share a video recording of the behavior) with specific examples.